# Passing API data as Observable from service > payment component > invoice component returns 0 or undefined

Tags: angular, http, typescript, rxjs

I created an API service, which returns a transactionID from Stripe. I want to pass that transaction ID from sibling component "Payment" to sibling component "Invoice".
Invoice-component has a download link, that needs the transactionID. I'm fairly new to the RxJS lib, but I think i got the point of the BehaviorSubject somehow.

*What is the expected behavior:*

When I enter the payment-component and buy and item, the StripeAPI returns a transactionID. The router navigates to /invoice component, and the mentioned TransactionID from the payment-component should be passed forward to this component as an Observable (or any kind of variable honestly).

*The outcome:*

I set up the service with a BehaviorSubject and a function that returns the value from it. When i call and subscribe to that function inside my payment-component, it works fine. When i do this in the sibling component, it returns the default value (0).

*Code:*

Service:

```
  private transId = new BehaviorSubject<any>(0);
  cast = this.transId.asObservable();


  sendTransId(transId: any) {
    this.transId.next(transId);
  }
```

Payment component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.paymentSrv.cast
      .subscribe(data => {
      this.transId = data);
    console.log(this.transId);
   }
  }



pay(item) {
    this.paymentSrv.buyStory(storyId)
      .subscribe(payment => {
          console.log(payment.Transaction.id);
          const transactionID = payment.Transaction.id;
          this.paymentSrv.sendTransId(transactionID);
        }
      })
  }
```

Invoice component (sibling):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.paymentSrv.cast
      .subscribe(data => this.transId = data);
}
```

This is the function that should be called with the transID:

```
seeInvoice(transactionID) {
    window.location.replace(`test-platform/invoice/${transactionID}`);
  }
```

Comment: Did you add your service to the  `providers`  in `ngModule` and no to the `providers` in the components? Because now it seems like you have two instances of service.

Comment: Omg, it actually worked.. Thank you so much, how the f*ck didn't I realize this. I used the service as a provider in the components. Cheers mate.

Comment: As a side question. I can only get this behavior, if i run the buy() function. Should i store the transID in the localstorage too, because the transactionID doesnt get provided, if you already bought the story.

Comment: You can use ReplaySubject if you want previous value to always available.

Comment: Cheers mate, ill look into it! Thanks.

Comment: @Chybie Are you sure this works? http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#replaysubject
It can send old values, but if the value is never received after a refresh (f.x), theres no initial data, and therefore no previous subscription.